# changing private variable in the same class?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am working on an c++ hw assignment so I will try not to post too much code as possible, what we are working on is as following: we have a class that include a public swap function (along with insert and delete functions and such) and a private struct array to store the data.

something like:

```
Class set
public:
set(int dimension);
insert();
delete();
swap(set& swapset);
private:
struct *set;
```

now in the main we have set s1 and set s2, when I run swap like so: s1.swap(s2); s1 and s2 will swap the whole array and we need to keep the dimension of each array (so if s1 was set=new set[3] and s2 is set=new set[5]) after swap s1 is [5] and s2 is [3]

I was able to use insert and delete functions to swap the arrays when it was fixed dimension but I can't figure out how to change the dimension of the arrays during the swap function since the *set is private right?

thanks in advance for all the help!

edit: I added some parts of the code since I can't explain it correctly:

```
  set::set()
    :counter(0),m_size(0),flag(0)
    {
    m_set=new set[DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS];
    swapper=new set[DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS];
    maxsize=DEFAULT_MAX_ITEMS;
    }
    set::set(int x)
    :counter(0),m_size(0),flag(0)
    {
    m_set=new set[x];
    swapper=new set[x];
    maxsize=x;
    }

void set::swap(set& other)
        {

    // Exchange the contents of this set with the other one.
        int tempmaxsize=maxsize;
        int tempcounter=counter;
        int tempmsize=m_size;

        swapper=m_set;
        m_set=other.m_set;

        other.m_set=swapper;

        m_size=other.m_size;
        counter=other.counter;
        maxsize=other.maxsize;

        other.counter=tempcounter;
        other.m_size=tempmsize;
        other.maxsize=tempmaxsize;
        }

private:

    struct set
        {
        ItemType entry;
        int count;
        };
    int maxsize;
    set* m_set;
    int m_size;
    int counter;
    int flag;
    set* swapper;
```

error code is this:
debug assertion failed!
expression:_block_type_is_valid(phead->nblockuse)

Comment: How do you track the dimension of the array now? Im guessing `std::vector` is offlimits?

Comment: Does your environment not support the standard container classes? Or is there another reason you don't use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)?

Comment: "how to change the dimension of the arrays"... hmmm, I do not see any **array** in your code. Just a pointer to unnamed struct. BTW, give us whole class declaration (maybe with a body of constructor)

Comment: Regardless of whether your member is `private`, `protected` or `public` the member functions of the same class should be able to access it. Show the code and the error.

Comment: I added some of the code to clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

Actually changing array sizes should be part of the `swap` function and so should be done in a class method. As it is a class method, it has access to private members.

Comment: I figured that it is possible to just do m_set=other.m_set but I keep on running into destructor error showing the error code above

Comment: When dealing with dynamic memory you should define the big four - copy constructor, destructor, assignement operator and empty constructor.